# jQuery not working click() and .css()

Tags: jquery, click

HTML code

```
<tr>
    <td class="name">ABC</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
    <td><button>CLICK ME</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="name">XYZ</td>
    <td>MNP</td>
    <td><button>CLICK ME</button></td>
</tr>
```

jQuery code

```
 $("button").click(function() {
        $(".name").css("color","red");
    });
```

Cant understand why is it not working

Comment: try putting the code in `document.ready`

Comment: Clicking any button should make all the `.name`'s red. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is intended. While i was trying to eat and code that, Rejith has a good example. Just use his...me too lazy

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'button', (function() {
         $(this).closest('tr').find('.name').css("color","red"); 
    });
});
```